# Relationship between wide sense cyclostationary process and jointly wide sense stationary processes

Tags: stationary, cyclostationary-random-process

https://faculty.engineering.ucdavis.edu/gardner/wp-content/uploads/sites/146/2014/05/Cyclostationarity_Half_a_century_of_research.pdf

According to the paper above (page 654~655), a CT wide sense cyclostationary signal can be expressed in terms of jointly wide-sense stationary signals with non-overlapping spectral bands.

At the first glance, this statement intuitively makes sense, but as I think about the definition of the jointly wide-sense stationary signals, it starts falling off.

For instance, the definition of jointly wide-sense stationary signal is that its second-order statistics are only a function of time difference between two wide sense stationary processes.
However, I am confused if this statement imply that these two wide sense stationary processes must have the same frequency. If not, how can their statistics be only a function of time difference and not a function of their absolute time index?

it is very possible that I'm confused with deterministic signals and that is why I think their statistics must be a function of their absolute time index.

But if anyone can clarify my misconception and wrong arguments raised above and give me kind feedback, I would greatly appreciated.